# Using Protocol buffers in PhoneGap - iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, protocol-buffers, hybrid-mobile-app

I have used the c++ google protobuf classes in iOS using the native app approach, i.e. using Xcode, objective c, cocoa etc.

Now, I want to migrate to hybrid apps and I have explored the options on web, and according to my requirements i'm down to PhoneGap and Titanium. That will require me to use JavaScirpt, HTML5 (JavaScript only in Titanium as per my understanding) jQuery etc.

My question is, HOW am i supposed to access the my c++ protobuf classes from javascript. (i have no expertise in JavaScript).

I am also open to opinions on which hybrid-app framework to use.

Lords of web-dev....guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With PhoneGap, if there is a phone feature that the PhoneGap APIs do not currently expose, or if you have some specialised native algorithm / function that you wish to access, then you need to write a plugin.

PhoneGap plugins provide a standardised mechanism for packing native code and accessing its functionality via JavaScript. See the [PhoneGap Plugin Development Guide](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/guide_plugin-development_index.md.html).

Personally I think PhoneGap is the best hybrid framework, it had been around for a while, is well documented, and has a healthy community.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What about in Titanium? They say that we can use the native code directly. I'm really not sure how

Comment: Titanium runs JavaScript within a VM on the device, and renders a native UI. It is not a HTML5 hybrid framework - it uses JavaScript but not HTML. Titanium also has a plugin concept that allows you to write bindings to native modules. To get a feel for the different frameworks, have a look at http://www.propertycross.com

Comment: _ok i know this might be a bad qn for the forum, But pls humour me._ If i go ahead with Phonegap, which of the two - Sencha touch and jQuery mobile, will be easier for a beginner. Also given the circumstances that I have to add the Phonegap plugin

Comment: @TusharKoul - I'd go for jQueryMobile, it is simpler - and there are loads of tutorials online. Sencha Touch is more complex, a bit more powerful, but takes a long time to learn.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but you can always use the [100% JavaScript implementation of ProtoBuf](https://github.com/dcodeIO/ProtoBuf.js) in your JavaScript code. It works well, and you can even precompile the .proto file if you want.

In Cordova it *would* be better to create a plug-in, but if you don't have time or skill to do that, the linked code works well.